# NextJS 13 - How to hide API response to user?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

How can I prevent the user from accessing `../api/post` and seeing the data. Or make it difficult.

[image]

I want only my site to consume the api and not allow the user to see it.

Prevent or make it difficult for some other application to consume mine.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't and, given the response is presumably shown to the user in some format anyway, it's unclear why you'd want to.

Comment: @jonrsharpe. Prevent or make it difficult for some other application to consume mine.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent data scraping and safeguard your API from excessive traffic, I suggest implementing minute-based limits. For instance, you could restrict the number of requests a bot can send within a minute, leading to potential banning if exceeded. It's important to note that completely halting scraping might not be achievable; however, you can make the process more challenging. By implementing measures such as traffic reduction and limit enforcement, you can discourage scraping attempts. These measures would likely impact beginner web scrapers more significantly than experts.